# SSRS Distinct Count Of Condition Once Per Group

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Let's say I have data similar to this:

```
|NAME  |AMOUNT|RANDOM_FLAG|
|------|------|-----------|
|MARK  |   100|       X   |
|MARK  |   400|           | 
|MARK  |   200|       X   | 
|AMY   |   100|       X   |
|AMY   |   400|           | 
|AMY   |   300|           |
|ABE   |   300|           |
|ABE   |   900|           |
|ABE   |   700|           |
```

How can I get a distinct count of names with at least one RANDOM_FLAG set.  In my total row, I want to see a count of 2 since both Mark and Amy had the flag set, regardless of how many times it is selected.   I have tried every thing I can think of in SSRS.  I'm guessing there is a way to nest aggregates to get to this, but I can't come up with it.  I do have a group on NAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional `COUNTDISTINCT` in SSRS.

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(
  IIF( not ISNOTHING(Fields!Random_Flag.Value) and Fields!Random_Flag <> "",Fields!Name.Value,Nothing),
  "DataSetName"
)
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the name of your dataset.

Comment: That works great.  It's simple and makes sense, but for some reason was alluding me...

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(name) from table_name where name in (select distinct name from table_name where random_flag="x");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for an SSRS solution.  Obviously my example was simple, but the true query is much more complex than this and would not work well with a subquery.